# Odd syntax in Salesforce VisualforcePage Title Attribute: $Label.Site.my_profile_page

Tags: visualforce, merge-field

We have a Visualforce Page that was built by a 3rd party and the title has some odd syntax.

`title={$Label.Site.my_profile_page}`

I looked on the documentation of the [VisualForce Developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_labelsite.htm) and couldn't find anything. Referencing custom values for the $Label.Site syntax.

I found another reference on this thread, but didn't have anything that was obvious about what the suffix, `my_profile_page` was doing.

Anyone have any documentation or just an explanation they can share?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation may be outdated or may have omitted this value. It is a standard label, as it exists in my org, and I definitely have not set up a custom label by this name.